# SQL Server : achieve unique constraint except one value which can be repeated

Tags: sql-server, database, constraints, unique-constraint

I have a `Student` table having uniqueness on combined key `[Name, Status]`. I can mark particular student as deleted but later I can enroll him in. Basically I can have multiple entries with same name and `Deleted` status. But if I apply unique constraint, then it won't allow me to do so.

So I created a new function which accepts name and status. If status is deleted, then it return trues, if other than deleted, then it returns number of records.

Inside check I am checking if returned value is less than 1, only then I allow a new insert. When I invoke this function, it shows proper result but putting in `CHECK` constraint doesn't work.

Records

```
ID   Name    Status
-------------------
1    Ram     Deleted
1    Ram     Deleted
2    Sham    Active
2    Sham    Deleted
```

I can insert record for

```
2 Sham Deleted
```

but it should not allow

```
2 Sham Active
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: why you will want to insert "2 Sham Deleted" ?Question should be like If I want to insert "Sham" then it won't allow becasue there is one active "sham".But if I want to insert Ram then new record with Ram will be inserted with Active status.Anyway below uniuw index will work in both the case.

Answer (score 12):

You are looking for a filtered index.  You want the student to be unique when not deleted.

```sql
    create unique index unq_student_id_active
        on student(name)
        where status = 'Active';
```

Filtered indexes in SQL Server are a recent addition; if they don't work on your version, tag your question with the version you are using.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes?view=sql-server-ver16)